# Paging Error :The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am Doing Paging in MVC on Index Page ..on this Line I got error

```
return View( employee.ToPagedList(Page ?? 1,3));
```

here is Index Method

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search, int? Page, string sortBy)
    {
        ViewBag.SortNameParameter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "Name desc"
            : "";

        ViewBag.SortGenderParameter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "Gender desc"
            : "Gender";

        var employee = db.Employees.AsQueryable();

        if (searchBy == "Gender")
        {
            employee = employee.Where(x => x.Gender == search || search == null);
        }
        else
        {
            employee = employee.Where(x => x.FUllName .StartsWith(search ) || search == null);
        }

        switch (sortBy)
        {
            case "Name desc":
                employee = employee.OrderByDescending(x => x.FUllName);
                break;

            case "Default":
                employee = employee.OrderBy(x => x.FUllName);
                break;
        }

      return View( employee.ToPagedList(Page ?? 1,3));
    }
```

I am not using Skip method ... But there is this error :

> The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to
>   Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method
>   'Skip'.

I read Similar Posts

[The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222694/the-method-skip-is-only-supported-for-sorted-input-in-linq-to-entities-the-me)

[How to solve "The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800908/how-to-solve-the-method-skip-is-only-supported-for-sorted-input-in-linq-to-en)

[The method ‘Skip’ is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method ‘OrderBy’ must be called before the method ‘Skip’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705926/the-method-skip-is-only-supported-for-sorted-input-in-linq-to-entities-the-me)

[ASP.NET MVC 3 PagedList. The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660726/asp-net-mvc-3-pagedlist-the-method-skip-is-only-supported-for-sorted-input-in)

and did following changes ...

1.Put employee.Where code before the switch statement:

2.Add a default case in your switch statement, and make it throw.
case "Default":
                    throw new ArgumentException("error", sortBy);

3. Use the type IOrderedQueryable.

   IQueryable employee = db.Employees.AsQueryable();

this doesnot solve problem ..
mostly they use to have Skip method .. But i Dont have ... and Other posts query are complex one ..

Please suggest whats missing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do have a `Skip` method.

The `PagedList` added it for you. Check the code out. That's how paging works, `Take` and `Skip`.

Also I think your case statement was meant to be

```
    switch (sortBy)
    {
        case "Name desc":
            employee = employee.OrderByDescending(x => x.FUllName);
            break;

        default: // Not: case "Default"
            employee = employee.OrderBy(x => x.FUllName);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: yes .. this is the answer ...default.. Not: case "Default" ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
    var employee = db.Employees.ToList()// Try to change AsQueryable to Ilist or List

    if (searchBy == "Gender")
    {
        employee = employee.Where(x => x.Gender == search || search == null).ToPagedList(Page ?? 1,3);
    }
    else
    {
        employee = employee.Where(x => x.FUllName .StartsWith(search ) || search == null).ToPagedList(Page ?? 1,3);
    }
     switch (sortBy)
    {
        case "Name desc":
            employee = employee.OrderByDescending(x => x.FUllName);
            break;

        case "Default":
            employee = employee.OrderBy(x => x.FUllName);
            break;
    }

      return View( employee);
```

Comment: then Type conversion error comes...Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<_SearchDemo.Models.Employee>' to 'PagedList.IPagedList<_SearchDemo.Models.Employee>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) ...

Comment: I tried to typecast employee to IPagedList<Employee> type and var type .. but that doesnt solve issue

Comment: Then change  var employee = db.Employees.AsQueryable(); to  IList<Employee> employees